# pass var jfrom JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, variables, ocpjp

In my code the $vl var is empty. Why?

JS;

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
     var vl = "ciao";

    });
  </script>
```

PHP:

```
  <?PHP
    $vl= "<script>document.write(vl); </script>";
     echo "bariabile:  ".$vl;
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass value from javascript to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327607/pass-value-from-javascript-to-php)

Answer (score 1):

This simply wont work, do try to read a few more tutorials and references for both php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Hs:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
     var vl = "ciao";
     window.location.href = "TEST_YT.php?nm=" +vl;

    });
  </script>
```

PHP:

```
?PHP
$vl= "<script>document.write(vl); </script>";
 echo "bariabile:  ".$_GET['nm'];
?>
```